# Deep Learning Log Likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, log-likelihood

I am new babie to the Deep Learning field, and I am use log-likelihood method to compare the MSE metrics.Could anyone be able to show how to calculate the following 2 predicted output examples with 3 outputs neurons each. Thanks

yt = [ [1,0,0],[0,0,1]]

yp = [ [0.9, 0.2,0.2], [0.2,0.8,0.3] ]

Comment: You should add more detail, because after reading the question, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

**[MSE or Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)** is simply the expected value of the squared difference between the predicted and the ground truth labels, represented as

```
\text{MSE}(\hat{\theta}) = E\left[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2\right]
```

where ***theta*** is the ground truth labels and ***theta^hat*** is the predicted labels

I am not sure what are you referring to exactly, like a theoretical question or a part of code

As a **Python** implementation

```
def mean_squared_error(A, B):    
     return np.square(np.subtract(A,B)).mean()

yt = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1]] 
yp = [[0.9, 0.2,0.2], [0.2,0.8,0.3]]

mse = mean_squared_error(yt, yp) 
print(mse)
```

This will give a value of `0.21`

If you are using one of the DL frameworks like **[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)**, then they are already providing the [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error) which calculates the mse loss between tensors

```
tf.losses.mean_squared_error
```

where

```
tf.losses.mean_squared_error(
    labels,
    predictions,
    weights=1.0,
    scope=None,
    loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES,
    reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS
)
```

> **Args:**
>
> **labels:** The ground truth output tensor, same dimensions as 'predictions'.
>
> **predictions:** The predicted outputs.
>
> **weights:** Optional Tensor whose rank is either 0, or the same rank as labels, and must be broadcastable to labels (i.e., all dimensions
>   must be either 1, or the same as the corresponding losses dimension).
>
> **scope:** The scope for the operations performed in computing the loss.
>
> **loss_collection:** collection to which the loss will be added.
>
> **reduction:** Type of reduction to apply to loss.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> Weighted loss float Tensor. If reduction is NONE, this has the same
>   shape as labels; otherwise, it is scalar.